# Determining congruence between rows in R, based on key variable

Tags: r

I have a few large data sets with many variables. There is a "key" variable that is the ID for the research participant. In these data sets, there are some IDs that are duplicated. I have written code to extract all data for duplicated IDs, but I would like a way to check if the remainder of the variables for those IDs are equal or not. Below is a simplistic example:

```
ID X Y Z
1  2 3 4
1  2 3 5
2  5 5 4
2  5 5 4
3  1 2 3
3  2 2 3
3  1 2 3
```

In this example, I would like to be able to identify that the rows for ID 1 and ID 3 are NOT all equal. Is there any way to do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` for this:

```
d <- read.table(text='ID X Y Z 
1  2 3 4 
1  2 3 5 
2  5 5 4 
2  5 5 4 
3  1 2 3 
3  2 2 3 
3  1 2 3
4  1 1 1', header=TRUE)

tapply(duplicated(d), d[, 1], function(x) all(x[-1]))

##     1     2     3     4 
## FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Duplicated returns a vector indicating, for each row of a dataframe, whether it has been encountered earlier in the dataframe. We use `tapply` over this logical vector, splitting it in to groups based on `ID` and applying a function to each of these groups. The function we apply is `all(x[-1])`, i.e. we ask whether all rows for the group, other than the initial row, are duplicated?

Note that I added a group with a single record to ensure that the solution works in these cases as well.

---

Alternatively, you can reduce the dataframe to unique records with `unique`, and then split by `ID` and check whether each split has only a single row:

```
sapply(split(unique(d), unique(d)[, 1]), nrow) == 1

##     1     2     3     4 
## FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

(If it's a big dataframe it's worth calculating `unique(d)` in advance rather than calling it twice.)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect! I must admit I'm very weak when it comes to using embedded functions like this -- something I definitely should work on. Thanks again!